# Asyncio http server loop setup

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a hard time to figure out how to add an aiohttp server to an array of loops in a non blocking way. The web server does not start :( Any idea what am I missing

```
async def webPing(self, handler):
    text = "OK"
    return web.Response(text=text)

async def webLoop(self):
    self.app = web.Application(loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
    self.app.add_routes([web.get('/ping', self.webPing)])
    web.run_app(self.app, port=8080)
    return

async def runMe(self):
     loops = [ self.webLoop() ]
     while not self.shutdown:
          try:
                await asyncio.gather(*loops)
          except Exception as e:
                log.error(f'Unhandled exception in gather loop {e}')
```

Comment: Where do you call the `runMe` function?

Comment: Multiple loops (or multiple servers) all bound to port 8080 cant work. Port 8080 is no longer free for a second loop. You can bind to different ports, or not bother as aiohttp handles multiple connections.